# How do I make the containers package match in stack for the version I want?

Tags: haskell, dependency-management, haskell-stack

In my cabal file I have the following build-depends:

```
  build-depends:       base >= 4.7 && < 5,
                       containers >= 0.5.10 && < 0.6
```

When I try to run `stack build` I get the following error:

```
Error: While constructing the build plan, the following exceptions were encountered:

In the dependencies for server-0.1.0.0:
    containers-0.5.7.1 must match >=0.5.10 && <0.6 (latest applicable is 0.5.10.2)
```

I had this problem with `cabal` I resolved it by using cabals's sandboxes. I don't know how to resolve this problem with stack by looking at the `--help` documentation, the error, the stack documentation and searching. How do I tell stack I want the newer version of containers if not via the cabal file?

I also tried running `stack install containers-0.5.7.1` which did not do what I expected it to. I see a containers in my list of installs. I noticed the [documentation](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/GUIDE/#adding-dependencies) says stack is sandboxed by default, but it's been very painful getting it to build this simple source file due to the containers dependency.

I noticed that this command reports the old version of containers, not the version I want:

```
$ stack list-dependencies
array 0.5.1.1
base 4.9.1.0
containers 0.5.7.1
deepseq 1.4.2.0
ghc-prim 0.5.0.0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try putting the following in `stack.yaml`:

```
extra-deps:
- containers-0.5.10.2
```

Another way to make it work is change your cabal constraints. Making it something like this should make it work:

```
 build-depends:       base >= 4.7 && < 5,
                      containers >= 0.5.7 && < 0.6
```

Note that right now only 0.5.7.1 is available in lts in Stackage.

Comment: Thanks! I ran ` stack solver --update-config` and did just this and now it build without errors. Thank you again!

Comment: I actually prefer 0.5.10.2 as it has new functions I find convenient so I did not want to reduce the version.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Sibi's great answer, I figured out that this command would automatically have resolved my dependency issue:

```
stack solver --update-config
```